# ActiveScaffold raise jquery.ui.core has already been required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline, activescaffold

I recently added Active Scaffold in my project. Everything worked fine on development machine. However when I try to deploy, it stops at asset precompilation step, raising the following error:

> jquery-ui-rails-4.2.0/app/assets/stylesheets/jquery.ui.core.css.erb
>   has already been required   (in
>   active_scaffold-3.3.3/app/assets/stylesheets/active_scaffold.css.scss)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's some time after you have asked your question, but the gem "turbo-sprockets-rails3" caused this kind of problem for me.